# Maple: assign derivative to function

Tags: derivatives, maple

This is probably a basic Maple question.  I'm trying to introduce $g$ as the derivative of $f$:

[image]

Somewhat puzzling, Maple now says $g$ is two times the function $x()$.

I've tried `g := x -> diff(f(x),x)` and `g := diff(f,x)`, but no luck. Google tells me I can use `subs(x=3,g)` to evaluate the derivative at $x=3$, but that's not very practical.

Is there a way to define a Maple function as the derivative of another Maple function?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.  Yes, if $f(x)= x^2$ then its derivative is $g(x)= 2x$.  That is clearly 2 times x as Maple says.  Every thing Maple is saying there is true.  Are you possibly confusing "x()" with "f(x)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **D** (capital D): **g:= D(f);** This is the functional derivative operator.

In your case:

```
f:=x->x^2;
g:=D(f);
g(3);
```

Comment: That works!  Found an explanation here  ["Notice the difference between diff and D: diff operates on an expression, and returns an expression while D operates on a function an returns another function."](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Maple/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 3):

The answer worked for the OP, but I have had trouble getting "D" to behave the way I want it to.  I found a solution using "unapply".  If the function is named **f**, then

```
fp:= unapply(diff(f(x),x),x)
```

creates a function **fp** that's the derivative of **f**.  `diff(f(x), x)` is an expression, and `unapply` converts it to a function of *x*.

This can also be done for functions of several variables (see Maplesoft's documentation for `unapply` here: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=unapply)

UPDATE: Hey there, in case anyone else feels compelled to suggest this be deleted, yes I know what "D" does.  It might do what you want most of the time.  But I've written code where "D" didn't behave the way I wanted to.  `unapply` is a decent workaround.  I see several other Maple users suggesting it in [this Maple forum](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/222727-Making-A-Function-Which-Is-The-Derivative).  One of them wrote "I find that in some situations D seems a little stupid, so often I prefer diff with unapply."

If you think there's something wrong with my answer, then a comment might be nice.  This workaround has worked for me and others when "D" didn't.

Comment: I found this works nicely for partial derivatives, too. Does D even have a partial equivalent? Thanks for introducing me to this command!

Comment: Yes.  If f is a function of more than one variable, then D[1](f) (a function) is the partial derivative of f with respect to its first argument, D[2](f) is the partial derivative of f with respect to its second argument, and so forth.  I haven't tried mixed or higher partial derivatives yet, but I'm sure it's easy to do, with some natural syntax.

By the way, my answer isn't intended to compete with the one above.  That solution is simpler, and if it works when one wants it, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original poster above, what you have defined `g:=diff(f(x),x)` is actually an expression, *not* a function. Therefore `g(3)` is equivalent to `2x(3)` because Maple thinks you want to multiply `g` and `3` or `2x(3)`. Maple does not not what else to do with it.

But why doesn't Maple allow you to evaluate `g(3)` when `g` and `f` are defined previously as
`g:=x->diff(f(x),x)`and `f:=x->x^2.` This is more interesting; you have defined here a valid function. Maple takes the `3` and evaluates `diff(f(3),3)` which is equivalent to diff(9,3). This is not a valid derivative, the second argument must be a variable.
At some point you have to use the `subs` command if you go on to make more complicated derivative expressions or functions.

Comment: It would be great if you gave an example of using the subs command for this use-case. I would have upvoted for that.